# How does entity framework access associations?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables, `Kittens` and `Owners` in my Entity Framework model. A `Kitten` has 1 `Owner` but an `Owner` can have many `Kitten`s.

I have a repository method called `GetKittens()` that returns `_context.Kittens.ToList();`

Since I set up an association, I can do `kitten.Owner.Name`.

But since ToList() was already called, and the context disposed of, how does it access the property? When retrieving an Entity, does it do a Join to all tables that have an association?

I have to write a query that pulls data from 4 tables, so I am wondering how to do this efficiently, hence this question trying to understand a bit more about how EF works.

Comment: Try running a db trace while you run the code - you'll see what is running when, which should help make things clearer.

Comment: ToList () will only give you your kittens. You need to `Select` them and `Include (kitten => kitten.Owner).ToList ()`.

Comment: Best project your selection into a type that includes the kittens and the properties of owner you're interested in.

Comment: I'm confused because I am able to access Owner without doing any Include

Comment: Its probably lazy loading the kitten to get Owner at the point where you ask for it. How sure are you that the context is disposed? - Having an entity still instantiated probably means it has a reference to the context itself.

Comment: my method is doing `using (var context = new mycontext)`, performing the operation, then ending the `using` which will call dispose() on the context.

Comment: Okay, you've solved that, the one time I used it is the one time I forgot to dispose the context! That explains that. So I will try your include() method, but if I include() several sets of results will that slow it down a lot?

Comment: I'm not sure you are correct... the code you posted seems to be using _context which is usualy used to denote a private variable. Are you sure you don't have multiple contexts? Where is your using statement, in the repository or elsewhere?

Comment: His explanation is correct, I created the context but never disposed of it, I thought I had. I guess I am wondering, since this is asp.net mvc, should I be keeping the context open for the lifetime of the request or using include() and closing it immediately?

Comment: Whatever comes after `.ToList()` isn't coming from EF but Linq to Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `DbContext` will use lazy loading. There is a few options available to you, depending on your use cases.

1- If you have control over the lifetime of your `DbContext`, do not dispose it. However, every time you will access a related entity (for the first time), a new query will be sent to the database to fetch it.

2- Eagerly include the related entity by use `Include` on the `IQueryable<Kitten>`:

```
// For imagine context is the DbContext for your EF Model
context.Kittens.Include(c => c.Owners); // Or Include("Owners")
```

However, if you have no control over your repository, you have no option but to call a related method of your repository (like `IEnumerable<Owner> GetOwners(Kitten kitten)`) since the repository already returns the list.

If you do, consider either eagerly include the Kitten's owners in the repository before materializing with `ToList()` or return an IQuerable and leave the responsibility to the calling class to include related entities or customizing the query. If you do not want a caller to be able to alter the query, you can add an overload with includes that could be something along the line of:

```
public List<Kitten> GetKittens(params string[] includes)
{
    return includes.Aggregate(
               context.Kittens.AsQueryable(), 
               (query, include) => return query.Include(include)).ToList();
}
```

All in all, this is an implementation decision that you will have to take.

Comment: I like that last one. I was wondering how to specify the includes I wanted, since I don't want Owners every single time. I was wondering if I should return `IQueryable` from my repository, and then I can add a .Include on it myself, but that way might be better.

Comment: It is really up to you. If you use my second suggestion, you can include multiple relation with: `GetKittens("Owners", "Owners.Pets")`. If it was me, I would return an IQueryable but this is solely because my repository is an abstraction over `DbContext` and `DbSet`s. This is really more a design choice. :)